# Need support for Azure AD B2C webapp integration

Tags: java, azure-ad-b2c

I am new to Azure AD B2C. 
I am trying to use Azure AD B2C for authentication with a Java web application, but there does not seem to be any guides or Java code samples to help.

Can anyone help with some basic code samples that could help explain how to integrate with a Java client?

Comment: Sample code (if it exists) can be found using a Google search

Comment: For general B2C samples, you can checkout github.com/azure-samples and search for "B2C" as a place to start (for code samples).

Comment: This question is not off topic in anyway, and should be allowed to be re-opened.

Comment: For some samples and java-api "in progress". take at look at blue-kit: https://github.com/Xitikit/xitikit-blue/tree/master/blue-kit

Answer (score 2):

There isn't currently a Java Azure AD B2C web app sample. I have written a [Azure AD v2.0 Java Web App Sample](https://github.com/danieldobalian/AADv2JavaMVC).  This app is a bit different than Azure AD B2C, but the code will be extremely similar.

I recommend checking out [the Azure AD B2C developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview) for help configuring a tenant & app, then use the sample code above and change the configurations for that of Azure AD B2C. After getting a basic understanding, you can use discovery endpoint to identify the specific configs your web app will need.

You can find the Azure AD B2C endpoints using the discovery url:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_sign_in/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Where `fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com` is the name of your tenant and `b2c_1_sign_in` is your Azure AD B2C policy.

For more info on what this means, I recommend reading the [Azure AD B2C Protocol & Token Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tokens).

Comment: Would you be interested in helping to create a Java API for Azure AD? I am focusing on integration with B2C right now, but I think it would be fun to work with someone else on it.