# Processing responses from Azure B2C flow

Tags: java, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am unable to understand how to consume and process responses that come back from Azure B2C once a user completes a flow and is back to my application.  Currently once they come back from Azure I get a response (encrypted I'm guessing) in the URL with a `code=` attribute.  I don't know what to do with that let alone how to decrypt it properly and use it to either to take my user forward or do something else in case of errors.

I did see there are end points for my flow by going to https://tenant.someurl.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=MY_FLOW_NAME

One of those is called jwks_uri and it does have an encryption key which I'm guessing I need to use somehow but I haven't been able to do anything with it.  I'm only guessing this is what I need to do.

I'm also not sure about response_code and response_type I need to be using.  Currently my response_type is "code" but I'm not sure if that's what I need.

Thank you in advance

Comment: have you check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695095/need-support-for-azure-ad-b2c-webapp-integration

Answer (score 0):

This flow is part of the [authorisation code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code) flow.

There are some [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples) you can refer to that use the MSAL library to do this for you.